# How to update selected headers only in a CSV using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to change my csv headers from

`column_1, column_2, ABC_column, column_4, XYZ_column`

To

`new_column_1, new_column_2, ABC_column, new_column_4, XYZ_column`

I can easily change all the columns using `writer.writerow` but the when there is a new value in place of ABC_column I want to keet that as well, meaning instead of ABC_column if it comes like DEF_column then I also don't want to change that.

So it should only change those columns which do not comes at 3rd place and 5th place and leave the ones that comes at 3rd and 5th place as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
df = df.rename(columns={'column_1': 'new_column_1', 'column_2': 'new_column_2' ... })

df.to_csv(path_to_csv)
```

you can do any type of renaming logic to that dictionary

Comment: Alternatively, once you have `df`, you can do `df.columns` to list them (easier to copy/paste) and then do `df.columns = ['column1', 'column2', ...]` and then `df.to_csv(`